# Clarification of Lemma $23.1$ from Munkres concerning the separation of a subspace. How do we know $A$ is open in $Y$?

Tags: general-topology, definition, proof-explanation

[image]

Do $A$ and $B$ have to be open in $X$? If not, how do we know $A$ is open in $Y$?

Do $A$ and $B$ have to be open in $Y$?

Answer (score 0):

We do not require anything about $A$ and $B$, just that they cover $Y$ and neither contain points from the closure of the other.

The connection to the intrinsic definition of $Y$ is that we may exchange $A$ for $A' = X\setminus \overline B$, the complement of the closure of $B$, and exchange $B$ for $B' = X\setminus \overline A$. Note that $A'$ and $B'$ are no longer disjoint in $X$, but they *are* disjoint in $Y$, because $A\cap Y = A'\cap Y$ and $B\cap Y = B'\cap Y$. This also shows that $A\cap Y$ and $B\cap Y$ are open in $Y$.

The reason the don't demand anything about openness or closedness in this lemma is probably because 1) By the above paragraph it makes no difference, and 2) It may make it easier in some concrete cases to construct such $A$ and $B$ is we're not required to make them open or closed, only disjoint from one another's closures.

Comment: If we do not know anything about $A$ and $B$, except that the union is $Y$, how do we know they are open?

Comment: @AlJebr As I was trying to say with my entire second paragraph is that we don't know that they are open. What we do know is that we can swap $A$ for $A' = X\setminus \overline B$ and swap $B$ for $B' = X\setminus \overline A$, and those _are_ open. Since we have $A\subseteq A'$ and $B\subseteq B'$, we have that $A'\cup B'$ still cover $Y$.

Comment: Munkres gives any separation of $Y$, $\{A, B\}$ and then states $A$ is open. How can he do this?

Comment: @AlJebr He's making a distinction between a separation of a space in and of itself, and separation of a subspace of a larger space. Anyways, it turns out that $A\cap Y$ and $B\cap Y$ _are_ open in $Y$, even though $A$ and $B$ aren't necessarily open in $X$.

Comment: How can $A \cap Y$ be open in $Y$ if $A$ is not required to be open in $X$?

Comment: @AlJebr Because $A$ is required to be disjoint from the closure of $B$. That means that $A'$ as defined above, which _is_ open in $X$, contains $A$. And $Y\cap A = Y\cap A'$, and by definition of subspace topology, the latter is open in $Y$.

Comment: When you say $A$ and $B$ cover $Y$, do you mean $Y= A\cup B$ or $Y \subset A\cup B$? Munkres defines the cover of a space differently than a cover of a subspace?

Comment: $A, B$ and $Y$ are clearly subsets of $X$ in this context, so I mean $Y \subseteq A\cup B$.

Comment: If $A$ is not open in $X$, how can we say $A \cap Y$ is open in $Y$? $A \cap Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $A$ is open in $X$.

Comment: @AlJebr No, that's not the definition of subspace topology. $A\cap Y$ is open in $Y$ if there is an open set $C\subseteq X$ such that $C\cap Y = A\cap Y$.

Comment: If $\tau$ is the topology on $X$, then $\tau_Y=\{Y \cap U \mid U \in \tau\}$.

Comment: You are mentioning $A\cap Y$ being open in $Y$. My question was, how do we know $A$ is open in $Y$?

Comment: @AlJebr Yes. I hope you agree that if $C\subseteq X$ is open, then $C\cap Y$ is open in $Y$. However, there may be _many_ sets in $X$ that are not open, but which intersect $Y$ the same way as $C$ does. $A$ might be such a set.

Comment: And I've said how we know that $A\cap Y$ is open in $Y$. We know this because $A\cap Y = A'\cap Y$ and $A'$ is open in $X$.

Comment: I am asking, how do we know $A$ is open in $Y$, not how is $A\cap Y$ open in $Y$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48974/discussion-between-al-jebr-and-arthur).